# Sencha Touch -- carousel or horizontal scrolling inside dataview?

Tags: html, css, extjs

I have an ExtJS 6.0.2 app using the modern(sencha touch) toolkit.

I have a dataview and upon swiping I want to slide some action buttons into view, similar to the Gmail app on iOS for example.

Currently I have two divs in my XTemplate, one that is shown initially while the other remains hidden. Upon swiping, I hide the first div and show the second by updating `div.style.display`. This works fine except the hidden div is not animated and does not slide into view as you're swiping like the carousel component.

So is there a way I can add a carousel or enable horizontal scrolling for each record in the dataview to slide another div element into view using swipe?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the issue.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.dataview.DataView', {
        fullscreen: true,
        itemTpl:
            '<div style="height: 64px; border-bottom:1px solid black;">{name}</div>',
        data: data,
        listeners:{
            swipe:{
                element:'element',
                delegate:'.x-dataview-item',
                fn:fn:function(event,target){
                    if(event.direction==='left'){
                        var target=Ext.get(target);

                        var button=Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
                            text:'Boo',
                            height:64,
                            width:200,
                            floated:true,
                            handler:function(button){this.hide()},
                            showAnimation:{
                                type:'slideIn',
                                 from: {
                                   top: target.getY()
                                 },
                            },
                            hideAnimation:{
                                type:'slideOut',
                                direction:'right'
                            }
                        });
                        this.add(button);
                        button.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The only issue is it doesn't cope with scrolling - unsure if you need to support this? You could try and re-position on scroll, or choose to just hide any visible buttons when they start to scroll.